# Como obter valor de uma função que esta dentro da outra função JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, funções

Fala galera, to com um problema.
Eu tenho o seguinte código com as devidas credenciais e não consigo fazer retornar o valor que retorna no .then(result), preciso fazer ele retornar um JSON nessa função com todas as linhas, ja tentei de tudo e nada funcionou
alguém poderia me ajudar? Ja estou um bom tento batendo cabeça com isso.
Segue o código

@EDIT---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Resultado da função na ibm cloud retorna assim, sem erros e sem linhas a monstra..

ID de ativação:
....
Resultados:
{}
Logs:
[]

```js
const sql = require('mssql');

function main(params) {
    var results;
    const config = {
        user: '',
        password: '',
        server: '',
        database: '',
        options: {
            "enableArithAbort": true
        },
    }
    sql.on('error', err => {
        console.log(err)
    })

     sql.connect(config).then(() => {
        return sql.query('SELECT * FROM TABLETESTE')
    }).then(result => {
         results = result.recordset;
        console.dir(result.recordset[0])
    }).catch(err => {
        console.dir(err)
    })
     return JSON.stringify(results); //<--
};
exports.main = main;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inicialmente reserve um minuto do seu tempo para ler sobre [Javascript Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) irá te ajudar muito.

Existem algumas maneiras de resolver o seu problema, mas a mais simples e mais bonita seria colocar tudo dentro a bloco `try/catch` e eliminar as callbacks, exemplo:

```
// Adicione a keyword "async" a sua função para indicar que a mesma retorna uma Promise
async function main(params) {
    const config = {
        user: '',
        password: '',
        server: '',
        database: '',
        options: {
            "enableArithAbort": true
        },
    }
    sql.on('error', console.log);
    
    try {
      // Dentro a função async, você pode usar a keyword "await" para esperar determinado resultado antes de proseguir com o código, se algo der errado ele vai direto para o bloco catch
      await sql.connect(config);
      const result =  await sql.query('SELECT * FROM TABLETESTE');
      
      console.log(result);
      return result.recordset;
      
    }catch(err){
      console.error(err)
    }
};
```